# How can we detect observations having different outcomes in R?

Tags: r, database, duplicates, panel, locate

I have a huge data in this form and with more other columns. So I have a list of people working in a country in 2011 and moved to another one in 2012.

```
Name  Work_{2011}     Work_{2012}     Wage_{2011}    Wage_{2012} 
  
Jack     US              UK            5387           35353
Bill     US              UK            43534          5343
Emma     US              FRANCE        34534          53455
Brand    US              FRANCE        64545          1343
Luigui   US              FRANCE        15343          3144
Ella     US              FRANCE        64545          1343       
Lucie    France          SPAIN         84545          1343
Maria    France          SPAIN         984545         1343
Grec     Italy           US            4545           1343
```

I want to keep the observations having the biggest share of destination for each departure. I want:

```
Name  Work_{2011}     Work_{2012}     Wage_{2011}    Wage_{2012} 
  
Emma     US              FRANCE        34534          53455
Brand    US              FRANCE        64545          1343
Luigui   US              FRANCE        15343          3144
Ella     US              FRANCE        64545          1343       
Lucie    France          SPAIN         84545          1343
Maria    France          SPAIN         984545         1343
Grec     Italy           US            4545           1343
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you were to read up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide your dataset in a form so other users can easily import it and show the code that you have produced so far. Clearly indicate what the current output is and what you would like it to be.

Comment: I would have loved to do that but my data access is limet in a box that is not connected to anything else. So I can neither export it nor copy past it or my codes..

Comment: I am not suggesting you share the actual data, but a very small set of toy data so folks can reproduce the problem. And clearly you have access to the internet, so you can use free file-sharing via google or other services to provide a public link to your toy data.

Comment: I see your point, I will try to make my request clearer. But I am using 2 different laptops one having access to internet and one just for data. It is some private data so I have just a BOX including this data and programs as R, Matlab... and you cannot export or import anything from/ to it... Otherwise it would have been easier for me to share it in the first place.

Comment: That's why I am saying you need to share a small toy example of fake data that demonstrates the problem. All 'real' data should stay safely on the other laptop.

Comment: that what i have done 10minutes ago. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this will meet your needs, but perhaps it will be helpful for you. It might help to know more details about your data, including how large your dataset is, how your columns are organized by year, etc.

In this example, you can use `dplyr` from `tidyverse`. First, you can `group_by` `Work_2011` (I removed the braces from column names), and `filter` where the number of distinct values for `Work_2012` is greater than 1. This would imply multiple destinations.

Second, you can `group_by` both `Work_2011` and `Work_2012` to determine the number of countries for each destination. This will be helpful in a second `filter`.

Again, please let me know if this is the direction you were interested in.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Work_2011) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Work_2012) > 1) %>%
  group_by(Work_2011, Work_2012) %>%
  mutate(numctry = n()) %>%
  group_by(Work_2011) %>%
  filter(numctry == max(numctry))
```

**Output**

```
  Name   Work_2011 Work_2012 numctry
  <chr>  <chr>     <chr>       <int>
1 Emma   US        FRANCE          4
2 Brand  US        FRANCE          4
3 Luigui US        FRANCE          4
4 Ella   US        FRANCE          4
```

**Edit (1/13/21)**: Based on edited question, we can simplify the code further.

Start by calculating the number of destinations per country, we'll call this `dest_per_cntry`. This will be a new column. For Jack and Bill, it will be 2. For Emma, Brand, Luigui, and Ella, it will be 4.

Then, you can `group_by` to consider the 2011 country only. For each country in the `Work_2011` column, keep (or `filter`) only those where the `dest_per_cntry` is the same as the maximum number of destinations for that country. Note that if there are "ties", all rows with the maximum destinations will still be kept.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Work_2011, Work_2012) %>%
  mutate(dest_per_cntry = n()) %>%
  group_by(Work_2011) %>%
  filter(dest_per_cntry == max(dest_per_cntry))
```

**Output**

```
  Name   Work_2011 Work_2012 Wage_2011 Wage_2012 dest_per_cntry
  <chr>  <chr>     <chr>         <int>     <int>          <int>
1 Emma   US        FRANCE        34534     53455              4
2 Brand  US        FRANCE        64545      1343              4
3 Luigui US        FRANCE        15343      3144              4
4 Ella   US        FRANCE        64545      1343              4
5 Lucie  France    SPAIN         84545      1343              2
6 Maria  France    SPAIN        984545      1343              2
7 Grec   Italy     US             4545      1343              1
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Jack", "Bill", "Emma", "Brand", "Luigui", 
"Ella", "Lucie", "Maria", "Grec"), Work_2011 = c("US", "US", 
"US", "US", "US", "US", "France", "France", "Italy"), Work_2012 = c("UK", 
"UK", "FRANCE", "FRANCE", "FRANCE", "FRANCE", "SPAIN", "SPAIN", 
"US"), Wage_2011 = c(5387L, 43534L, 34534L, 64545L, 15343L, 64545L, 
84545L, 984545L, 4545L), Wage_2012 = c(35353L, 5343L, 53455L, 
1343L, 3144L, 1343L, 1343L, 1343L, 1343L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: This was indeed very helpful. It is exactly what I am searching for. thank you very much!

Comment: I have another question, what if I wanted to also keep those other observations              
`Lucie   Maria  Grec   ` because they are also unique destinations

Comment: The `filter` statements remove/keep rows, but it is not clear exactly what logic you would like to use for this. If you'd like - edit your original post, and add what your final result should look like in keeping more observations. For example, if you want to keep Lucie, Maria, and Grec observations, what should it say for `numctry` for those 3 rows in this example? Or as an alternative, feel free to post this as a separate question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @M.KKK Please see edited answer with alternative code.

Comment: This works perfectly. + thanks to you I finally understood how the filter statements works. Thank you very much!